# What is the phase coded modulation?

Tags: modulation

I'm trying to understand what is the "phase coded modulation" and how does it work.

As far as I know, Although the linear frequency modulated (LFM)
waveform continues to be the workhorse of modern radars, there is growing interest in the use of
phase-coded (PC) waveforms.  Phase coding can be used to reduce radio frequency interference (RFI) 
between adjacent radars and make the waveform less vulnerable to exploitation, and more robust to
interference.

and I'm not a familiar with like these radio frequency engineering. So.

Is the [Phase modulation](https://kr.mathworks.com/help/comm/ref/pmmod.html) same "phase coded modulation"?
I'm confused that because there are several types modulation way in 
https://kr.mathworks.com/help/comm/ug/digital-modulation.html#fp45657

> - Kind of Modulation
> - Amplitude modulation
> - Phase modulation
> - Frequency modulation
> - Continuous phase modulation
> - Trellis-coded modulation

But I can't find anywhere about Phase coded modulation.

Would you help me to understand what is the "phase coded modulation" and how does it work with very very simple example for referencing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phase-coded modulation is another name for direct-sequence spread-spectrum (DS/SS) modulation. In a typical DS/SS *communication* scheme using binary phase modulation, a single bit is transmitted not as a sinusoidal pulse of duration $T$ and phase either $0$ or $\pi$ depending on whether the bit being transmitted is $0$ or $1$, but rather as a *sequence* of successive $N$ shorter sinusoidal pulses of duration $T/N$ with phases $0$ or $\pi$ as defined by a specific binary sequence (called a *spreading* sequence) $\mathbf b$ of length $N$ or its complement $\mathbf{\bar{b}}$ according as the data bit $d$ is $0$ or $1$. For example, with $N=7$, we would have a *phase-coded* transmission describable as
$$\begin{array}{ccccc}
d=0 &\leftrightarrow &\mathbf b = (1,1,1,0,1,0,0) &\leftrightarrow &(\pi,\pi,\pi,0,\pi,0,0)\\
d=1 &\leftrightarrow &\mathbf{\bar{b}} = (0,0,0,1,0,1,1) &\leftrightarrow &(0,0,0,\pi,0,\pi,\pi)
\end{array}$$
In the communication context, the interference between two different phase-coded transmissions using two different spreading sequences is determined by the *cross-correlation* between the spreading sequences. In the radar context, $\mathbf{\bar{b}}$ is not needed, but interference between two radar signals with different spreading sequences is still determined by the *cross-correlation* between the spreading sequences. The term *spreading* refers to the fact that the phase-coded signal has a bandwidth $N$ times larger than the non-phase-coded signal. Because the energy is spread over a larger bandwidth, the signal doesn't interfere as much with narrowband signals, and is not easy to detect even by broadband scanners. Thus, *covert* communication or *covert* scanning is easier, and signals are not that easy to jam, either by narrowband jamming or by broadband jamming, because the correlation receivers reject both kinds of jamming more easily.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know Sir. I'm not sure whether does it the same meaning between the phase-coded modulation and phase-coded compress ion? I want to know a way of phase-coded compression technic. can I use phase-coded modulation for phase-coded compression or They are totally different things? my goal is to know how to implement ( c or matlab )phase-coded compression but I'm not sure where to start from.

Comment: The use of the term "spread spectrum" should be avoided when describing pulse compression in radar. The terminology is misleading since the purpose of coded waveforms for pulse compression is different from their purpose in spread spectrum communications.